# Cross data in the same array with Twig

Tags: php, twig, slim-3

Sorry for the title, I was not inspired. 
I send (with Slim 3) to Twig an array with 'article' and 'categories'. In 'article', I have a article.cat.id and in 'categories' I have an 'id'. I want just to get the category name by article.cat.id. For the moment, I make a double loop but I assume that's a bad way to do this.
Any idea to do this in a better way? Thanks

```
{% for article in articles %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ article.title }}</td>
        <td>
            {% for category in categories %}
                {% if category.id == article.cat_id %}
                    {{ category.name }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}  
        </td>
        <td>{{ article.author }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do

```
{{ categories[article.cat_id].name }}
```

(unless the array index is different to the category id attribute)

Comment: Or use/write a getter `article.getCategoryId()`/  `article.getCategory()`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. My array must have my category id as key. To do that with eloquent is:

```
Category::all()->keyBy('cat_id');
```

and now I can use:

```
{{ categories[article.cat_id].name }}
```